# minitest: spec style inside test method?

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, minitest

I already have a few Test::Unit::TestCase based tests, with assertions. I wanted to add some context for each test in a similar fashion as provided by "describe" and "it" in Spec style tests (specially to show better context when a test fails). But I want to keep my current xUnit class hierarchy, setup/teardown methods (which I have in my base class), assertions, etc.

Is it possible to do this with minitest (or any other ruby test library)?

Comment: What is the main reason you want to move away from test-unit to mini-test?

Comment: I want to have better documentation of the checks done by my tests and to show that documentation in when a test breaks.